# git clone - Authentification failed

Tags: git, ssh, openssh

I try to clone a remote repository laying on a webserver.
However, if I try to clone it then a prompt appears, which asks me for username and password.

[image]

But If I enter the credentials for the ssh access, then I get "Authentification failed".

I have root access to the server and can login via ssh though. How can I clone that remote repository? Do I have to create a OpenSSH account on the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `root` access on the web server, consider [generating an `ssh` key with PuTTYGen](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows) and copying the generated public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (the file might not already exist - if so, create it), then try cloning the repository again.

Comment: I don't need the key file to enter the webserver via ssh though, why does git need it?

Comment: Just as a fault-finding experiment